# What regex do I need for Java String.split for this case

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm sorry I really don't know how to put into words how I want this to work.
I want to split numeric characters from alphabetic characters. If there is a hyphen in front of a number, I want to keep it there.

Looking through the previous questions I found `"(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"`

I implemented is like this:

`String s = "dfgsgf-89ff--989";
 String[] pieces = s.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");`

and it gave me this:

`peices[0] = "dfgsgf"-
 peices[1] = "89"
 peices[2] = "ff--"
 peices[3] = "989"`

what I really want is this:

`peices[0] = "dfgsgf"
 peices[0] = "-89"
 peices[0] = "ff"
 peices[0] = "--989"`

What regex will give me the result I want?

I've looked at the Java Patterns page, but I 'm still having trouble understanding how special constructs work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
String s = "dfgsgf-89ff--989";
String[] pieces = s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pieces));
```

OR

```
String[] pieces = s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=-*\\d)");
```

**Output:**

```
[dfgsgf, -89, ff, --989]
```

- `(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)` Matches the boundary which exists in-between a digit character and a non-digit character.
- `(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])` Matches the boundary which exists in-between an alphabetic character and a non-alphabetic character.

Comment: or `s.split("(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=-*\\d)");`